# Rewrite only the middle part of URL - mod rewrite .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change `cadeaushop` part in the url to `hobby-cadeau-shop`. I made the following  mod rewrite in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^cadeaushop/(.*) http://www.zovyo.nl/hobby-cadeau-shop/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works nice, but on one place I want something else. the shopping cart uses https, a secure url. Now this url is also set to http.

How can I change the mod rewrite so the first part of the url doesn't change? I tried some changes, like

```
RewriteRule ^cadeaushop/(.*) /hobby-cadeau-shop/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this don't work.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Martin

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `R` flag in your rule and avoid using `http://` or `https://` in target URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cadeaushop/(.*)$ /hobby-cadeau-shop/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Also important is to keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` OR `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: How to redirect transparently? dont change URL in browser

Comment: @Umair: Just remove `R=302` from the flags.