# Htaccess replace a segment of the URL in Wordpress?

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Problem**

I would like to redirect from `website.com/PRODUCT/name-of-item` to `website.com/COURSES/name-of-item`. There are too many products to do them individually.

Also, as the term `product` does appear in the `name-of-item` part sometimes (eg. `product-best-rating`), I need to be mindful of that.

Many users have asked similar questions. I have tried the solutions and they do not work for me.

**What I tried - Solution 1**

Solution 1: [Rewrite only the middle part of URL - mod rewrite .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801537/rewrite-only-the-middle-part-of-url-mod-rewrite-htaccess)

My code for Solution 1 is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /courses/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Results: https://website.com/product/normal-product/ still redirects to https://website.com/product/normal-product/

**What I tried - Solution 2**

Solution 2: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102402/how-to-bulk-redirect-urls-and-replace-one-path-segment

For Solution 2, my code would be this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?product/(.*)$ https://website.com/courses/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Results: https://website.com/product/normal-product/ still redirects to https://website.com/product/normal-product/

Comment: have you checked if you have some other rules that are in conflict with this?

Comment: Hi @Berto99, I have checked it and don't see anything that is conflicting. Thanks. Here is what is in my htaccess https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/duz5jfs2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have checked it and don't see anything that is conflicting.

The WordPress front-controller itself is conflicting with the redirect. By placing your directive after the WP directives, it's simply never going to get processed.

You need to place your redirect (the directive from either solution 1 or 2 looks fine) *before* the WordPress front-controller. In fact, you should place it before the `# BEGIN WordPress` block (near the start of the file), since WordPress will try to maintain that part of the code and will overwrite any custom directives.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*) /courses/$1 [R=302,NE,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
:
```

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive.

The trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is superfluous since regex is greedy by default.

---

> **UPDATE:** When you said "you don't need to repeat RewriteEngine On", do you mean that I can remove A Or do you mean B in this diagram...

[image: htaccess]

With WordPress, you should avoid manually editing the code in any section that is maintained by WordPress (or a plugin). If you do edit this code it is likely going to be overwritten later (by WordPress).

For this reason you should never manually edit the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers. I'm assuming the same applies to the `# BEGIN Security Block` as well. So, you should probably leave both the `RewriteEngine On` directives in-place (although the first one is actually superfluous).

The reason why you get multiple `RewriteEngine On` directives in a WordPress `.htaccess` files is because you potentially have multiple plugins all editing the `.htaccess` file and injecting their own directives. Each one will include a `RewriteEngine On` directive, since they are unaware of what else is in the `.htaccess` file.

However, from an Apache/.htaccess perspective only the **very *last* instance** of the `RewriteEngine` directive does anything - and this controls the entire file. So, if you are manually writing these directives then you would just have one `RewriteEngine On` directive at the top (just because that's more readable -  but the order does not strictly matter).

You could write a `RewriteEngine Off` directive at the very end of the file and this would disable the rewrite engine for the entire file, despite there being `RewriteEngine On` directives earlier in the file - these are essentially ignored. This is actually a quick way to "comment out" all the mod_rewrite directives, rather than manually using `#` in front of every directive.

So, if the `# BEGIN WordPress` block is still in place (with it's `RewriteEngine On` directive) - which you should not edit - then there is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive if you create your own custom redirects above this. That's all I was really saying initially.

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, it worked! Thank you :) Would you mind helping me out with the following?

**(1)** When you said "you don't need to repeat `RewriteEngine On`", do you mean that I can remove A Or do you mean B in this diagram (https://i.imgur.com/4biZVRt.png)?

**(2)** Also, when you said the `$` can be removed, so I would change it to this `RewriteRule ^product/(.*) /courses/1 [R=302,NE,L]`. Is this correct?

Thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome. 1) I was really just referring to my code above - you would not need to repeat `RewriteEngine On` before the `RewriteRule` directive I added. I'll update my answer with more info with regards to A and B from your diagram. 2) No, exactly as I wrote above. Only the "trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` pattern". The `$1` is a backreference (not part of a regex) and is required. I had already removed the trailing `$` in the code I posted. In regex `^product/(.*)` is the same as `^product/(.*)$` because "regex is greedy by default".

Comment: I've updated my answer with more of an explanation about the `RewriteEngine` directive (and the A and B in your diagram)

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, many thanks for taking time to provide such a detailed explanation! Looks like I really have a lot more to learn in this area. Have a great day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?product/(.*)$ /courses/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

I've tested [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and this URL

```
https://website.com/product/name-of-item
```

redirects to

```
https://website.com/courses/name-of-item
```

Comment: This is the same as what the OP has already tried and said isn't working?!